# Resolution Strategy in Gradle seems to be ignored

Tags: gradle

I have a Gradle project (7.5) that I am working on.  It has a bunch of dependencies and transitive dependencies and even transitive dependencies of transitive dependencies that are being blocked by my corporate Artifactory server. We have later versions of these dependencies available for use.

After doing some digging in the documentation I have figured that using a resolutionStrategy directive is what I want to use.  I came up with the following:

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        substitute module('org.mozilla:rhino:1.7R4') using module('org.mozilla:rhino:1.7.7')
        substitute module('org.yaml:snakeyaml:1.30') using module('org.yaml:snakeyaml:1.33')
        substitute module('com.google.javascript:closure-compiler-unshaded:v20210106') using module('com.google.javascript:closure-compiler-unshaded:v20200614')
        
        //force 'org.mozilla:rhino:1.7.7'
        //force 'org.yaml:snakeyaml:1.33'
        //force 'com.google.javascript:closure-compiler-unshaded:v20200614'

        //forcedModules = ['org.mozilla:rhino:1.7.7', 'org.yaml:snakeyaml:1.33', 'com.google.javascript:closure-compiler-unshaded:v20200614']
    }
}
```

I tried both force (now commented out) and then substitute.  Neither has any effect, the build still complains it cannot get the blocked dependencies.

Is there something I am missing that is allowing the proposed resolutionStrategy from being applied?

Answer (score 0):

The answer I found was RTFM.

Still not sure why the resolutionStrategy was ignored, but I found I was successful with including the versions of the transitive dependency I wanted and then excluding them from the dependency as found here:

https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_constraints.html

my resolution looks a little like this:

```
runtimeOnly ( "com.bertramlabs.plugins:asset-pipeline-grails:3.4.6" )
constraints {
    runtimeOnly('org.mozilla:rhino:1.7.7') {
        because 'the designated version of this transitive dependency is blocked in Artifactory'
    }
    runtimeOnly('com.google.javascript:closure-compiler-unshaded:v20200614') {
        because 'the designated version of this transitive dependency is blocked in Artifactory'
    }
}
```

The single line on the top was replaced by the entire block above